# Measured Grid won't show

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules

I'm fairly new at this, so maybe this is a simple issue.

I'm trying to make a map that shows a grid of 50 meter by 50 meter boxes.  I've done the Data Frame  Properties for a measured grid and made sure that the coordinate systems match, but no grid appears.

Comment: Do the grids only show up in Layout view or in Data View as well? Which are you in?

Answer (score 2):

Grids that you generate in the data frame properties only show up in layout view.  If you need a grid that you can see in data view you will need to build one that exists as a shapefile or feature class.

If you are in layout view and still can't see it go back to the properties dialogue for the grid and make sure your spacing is visible at the current scale and that the color of the lines/ticks is something you'll be able to see.

Comment: To create a grid (or graticule) as a feature class, you can use the Create Fishnet tool.

Comment: Thanks very much! Of course! I should have known to change the view. Thanks!